# MacBook Pro's audio doesn't work on a fresh Pop!_OS install

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, macintosh, pop-os

I have a MacBook Pro 16, and decided to install Pop!_OS on it.

Without any configuration, I just see a `Dummy Output` as output device:

[image: audio settings, showing dummy output]

Here is my most important system info:

```
OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64 
Host: MacBookPro16,2 1.0 
Kernel: 6.2.6-76060206-generic
```

I tried following [this](https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/) guide, to no avail. What I thought to be weird though is, that when checking if my audio card is detected, it actually is:

```
sudo lspci -v | grep -A6 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 38c8 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 165
    Memory at 9d630000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
--
e6:00.3 Multimedia audio controller: Apple Inc. Apple Audio Device (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Apple Audio Device
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at b0c00000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4M]
    Memory at b1180000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=512K]
    Memory at b1230000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
```

Despite that, when checking at what audio devices ALSA is detecting, it only shows some HDMI ports.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

With the hope it will be useful to my problem, [here my `alsa-info` output](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=cd6f66efe10c738aaa3760d24001e599e114d88e).

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so turns out, the mac book I was using has a T2 chip. I don't know why, but it causes problems. Some people patched the kernel and fixed the audio.

[All of those models have this chip](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862)

If you have this issue, and use Ubuntu or an Ubuntu based distro, you can change the Kernel, to a version that supports the T2 chip.

[Here are the instructions to do so.](https://github.com/t2linux/T2-Ubuntu-Kernel/tree/v6.2.6-1)

After installing the new Kernel, you need to boot in this, using you're boot manager. For me it was systemd-boot, so I could simply change the default boot entry. I don't know how you do it in grub, but it should be straight forward.

After a reboot, check if the kernel name contains `T2`, mine looks like this: `6.1.40-t2-jammy`

Your audio *should work*. If you also have issues with your wifi card, look at [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/752257/macbook-pros-wifi-doesnt-work-on-a-fresh-pop-os-install/752262#752262).