# MacBook Pro's wifi doesn't work on a fresh Pop!_OS install

Tags: wifi, drivers, network-interface, pop-os, broadcom

I have a MacBook Pro 16, and decided to install `Pop!_OS` on it.
My system info is:

```
OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64 
Host: MacBookPro16,2 1.0 
Kernel: 6.2.6-76060206-generic
```

My Network controller is a Broadcom Wireless Network Adapter (`Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter`). I found the a [helpful page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/broadcom_wireless) on the ArchWiki.

Running `sudo lspci -vnn -d 14e4:` to figure out which drivers I need yields the following:

```
e5:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4464] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:07bf]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at 81400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32K]
    Memory at 81000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4M]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/16 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [68] Vendor Specific Information: Len=44 <?>
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number 1d-b9-fb-ff-ff-ba-3c-22
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [1b0] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] Physical Resizable BAR
    Capabilities: [240] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac, wl
```

To Quote the archwiki:

> The kernel contains two built-in open-source drivers: brcmfmac for native FullMAC and brcmsmac for mac80211-based SoftMAC. They should be automatically loaded when booting.

So it should work (?) But it doesn't.

When looking at the blacklisted kernel modules, I found `brcmfmac` to be blacklisted.

```
pop-os:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
# Warning: This file is autogenerated by bcmwl. All changes to this file will be lost.
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
```

I commented it out, saved, and ran `sudo update-initramfs -u`, but didn't help.

Because the Network Card seems to accept the `wl` driver, I checked if it is loaded (`$ lsmod | grep wl`), and it seems to be loaded.

```
wl                   6488064  0
cfg80211             1241088  1 wl
```

brcmfmac however, is not loaded (`$ lsmod | grep brcmfmac` yields nothing).

running `$ sudo modprobe brcmfmac` loads the module.

```
$ lsmod | grep brcmfmac
brcmfmac              503808  0
brcmutil               20480  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211             1241088  2 wl,brcmfmac
```

That's certainly cool, my wifi still doesn't work though.
At this point I have no more idea what to do.

Here some more detailed network information:

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:e5:00.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:81400000-81407fff memory:81000000-813fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       bus info: usb@2:1.4
       logical name: enx00e04c680604
       serial: 00:e0:4c:68:06:04
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 ip=192.168.0.129 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

And that's how the not working wifi looks in the settings:

[image: Not working wifi in settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so turns out, the mac book I was using has a T2 chip. I don't know why, but it causes problems. Some people patched the kernel and fixed the wifi.

[All of those models have this chip](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862)

If you have mac os still installed besides your linux installation, follow [this guide](https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/wifi-bluetooth/). *[Credits to this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/752262/550711)* If you don't, it will be a bit harder.

If you have this issue, and use Ubuntu or an Ubuntu based distro, you can change the Kernel, to a version that supports the T2 chip.

[Here are the instructions to do so.](https://github.com/t2linux/T2-Ubuntu-Kernel/tree/v6.2.6-1)

After installing the new Kernel, you need to boot in this, using you're boot manager. For me it was systemd-boot, so I could simply change the default boot entry. I don't know how you do it in grub, but it should be straight forward.

After a reboot, check if the kernel name contains `T2`, mine looks like this: `6.1.40-t2-jammy`

If it doesn't work after swapping your Kernel you can try to manually load the driver with `sudo modprobe brcmfmac`. If this works, you should check if you blacklisted `brcmfmac` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf`. If you did, unblacklist it and run `sudo update-initramfs -u`. If it doesn't work then after a reboot, your hardware will be different to mine.

After you've loaded the new Kernel, you might want to check if you have `brcmfmac` blacklisted. Just comment it out. For me it was blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf`. Run `sudo update-initramfs -u` after you unblacklisted it, and then pray.

If this fixed your wifi, but it is unstable, you can find a fix [here](https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/wifi-bluetooth/#fixing-unstable-wpa2-using-iwd).

Answer (score 1):

Your MacBookPro16,2 is equipped with a T2 chip, which apparently causes a new set of complications. Fortunately your kernel seems to be new enough so that it probably does not need patches, but apparently the firmware for your WiFi chip would have to be extracted from MacOS:

https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/wifi-bluetooth/

Comment: Are you aware of any way, to do this without having a mac os Installation?

Comment: I found a sollution, that does this. But it is too long for a comment.